# Insert custom field value before content

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, add-filter

I have a custom meta field that I would like to insert in the_content automatically so that my AMP plugin can render the custom field value in the same way as the_content.

Currently I am using this code to display it:

```
<?php $video_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_video', true ); ?>

<?php if ( ! empty( $video_value ) ) {?>
    <div class="video-container"><?php echo $video_value; ?></div>
<?php } else { ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

But I would like the `$video_value` to be inserted automatically before `the_content`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `the_content` filter to do this. You can read more about it on the [WordPress developer site](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/).

But the code could be looking something like this:

```
function my_custom_content_filter($content){
  global $post;
  $video_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_video', true);
  if($video_value){
    return '<div class="video-container">' . $video_value . '</div>' . $content;
 }else{
   return get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID) . $content;
 }
}
add_filter('the_content', 'my_custom_content_filter');
```

And you can add this code in you `functions.php` file.

**Note** This filter only works on `the_content()` and not `get_the_content()`

Comment: argh - you wrote it for him! :-D My answer was for him to figure some of it out for himself -_-

Comment: hehe, well your answer is a bit better for education purpose :P

Comment: Thanks both you you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this -

and add the conditions that you want -

You might need to access Global $post to get the meta value

```
function custom_weird_name_before_after($content) {
if(is_page() || is_single() || $yourOwnConditions == true)  {
    $beforecontent = 'This line will go before the content - populate with whatever.';
    $aftercontent = 'This will come after the content - makes sense right?';
    $fullcontent = $beforecontent . $content . $aftercontent;
} else {
    $fullcontent = $content;
}

return $fullcontent;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'custom_weird_name_before_after');
```

You can add this in functions.php